# Calculating expected receive power

Tags: rf

I am using a TI CC1120 + CC1190 combination to transmit data wirelessly using Sub 1 GHz link. My output power is about 27dBm according to the CC1190 SOC.

I want to determine the maximum power (an approximate) that I would be able to see (through RSSI readings) of the receiver circuit (another CC1120 + CC1190) if the boards are about 1-2 meters apart.

I currently receive about -25 - -30 dBm when I keep them a couple of meters apart but I intend to know a usual ballpark RSSI figure that can be read from a receiver when the tx is about 27dbm.

Comment: Did you buy a module featuring those two chips or did you build a custom board? I've been looking for an evaluation module with CC1120+CC1190, but it seems that TI no longer sells it.

Comment: please do a post TI official forum. Those modules are yet to come to the TI Estore.But if you kindly insist, they will provide you.

Comment: within three months time, I was told this combination would be ready to purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to estimate how much power you will receive you can use the [Friis transmission equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation) to get a rough estimate.

$$
P_r = P_t + G_t + G_r + 20log_{10}({\lambda \over {4\pi R}})
$$

The \$P_r\$ is the power received the \$P_t\$ is the power transmitted that you determined you're sending, the \$G\$s are gains of the transmitting and receiving antennas respectively (in dB) and the final bit is the isotropic antenna equation, which will tell you how much power was 'lost' because it was not directed at your receiving antenna.

Comment: Thank You so much for your explanation Samuel. Can units of all be in dBm and not in dB? could that be possible? my antenna do not speak of a gain value https://store.ti.com/CC1120EMK-868-915-CC1120-Evaluation-Module-Kit-868915MHz-P2536.aspx How do I figure this out?

Comment: @QwertyCoolGuy The power values can be in dBm if you want, dB is a *power ratio*, so you can add or subtract those from dBm or dBW and still end up with whichever you started with. Take a look [at this](http://www2.tu-ilmenau.de/nt/en/private_home/roemer/dB_cheatsheet.pdf) to learn more. Your antenna does say its gain, look at the [antenna datasheet](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/W5017/W5017-ND/3025810), it's 2 dB.

Comment: thanks for the cheat sheet! I guess I should ask TI for the gain for their antenna and substitute to this equation. I think I should also take into the account the antenna loss that happens when signal is fed into it. Dont you think? Lets say if a signal of 27dBm is fed to an antenna of 3dBm gain, what about the feeding loss?

Comment: @QwertyCoolGuy There are extended version for the Friis equation that also include return loss, which is the reflection from mismatch at the antenna. You're on the right track at least. TI probably has some network analyser measurements for their boards, those will give you values to work from.

Comment: Now I get it! feeding loss is caused by miss match!!! So can I make a perfect match, or at least somewhere close to a perfect match to avoid feeding losses? okay. I will seek their forum too for more statistical results. thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: @QwertyCoolGuy Right, it's called return loss because that power is *returned* to the transmitter. You can reduce that loss, but you're getting into transmission lines, and that is the realm of dark magic in electrical engineering. I wish you luck there, it's equal parts fascinating and confusing.

Comment: There is an error in this equation, the last term should be 20log and not 10log. This is because the term inside the log was initially squared.

Comment: @RogerC. Quite right, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You could always calibrate your RSSI readings with an known input power, say with a generator or similar, then you subtract the offset and should have a good RSSI reading.